# Not getting all values passed through API

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, parameters

Im using a web api to make my Index page and i have a VM i guess you would call it that i use to make the Index page based on the data i get from my API GET request.

Only problem is im getting all of the values returned besides the Contact.ID which i need for a details page.

Ill post my methods below for retrieving the data with the GET and my details methods.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Contact> lst = new List<Contact>();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56194/");
        //CODE BELOW IS TAKING THE CLIENT AND ALLOWS IT TO ACCEPT JSON DATA
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts").Result;
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            lst = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Contact>>().Result;
        }
        return View(lst);


    }



My Web Api method is as follows:


  public List<contact> Getcontacts()
    {
        return db.contacts.ToList();
    }
```

But when i debug and i look at the list of contacts called lst i see all of the correct information but the ID parameter stays at 0 even though when i pull up my explorer and check the table data it says my correct ID

Thanks,

Comment: If more information is needed please just ask

Comment: Is your server sending the correct data? And don't use `GetAsync().Result` since it makes the whole async pointless

Comment: Yeah all the data being sent is correct but when I click on the list in debug mode I have all the correct data but the ID value is null.

Comment: I have a post method and when it creates the object the Id is 0 but after creation it takes the primary key I set in SQL Database but when I pull data it doesn't show the Id but if I click on server explorer and open my table data it shows the Id it should be